# Storing data from a plist file into an array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary, plist

I have spent all of yesterday trying to figure this out with no luck at all. Here is the code im working with.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"root"]];

for(int num = 0; num < 5; num++)
{
NSLog(@"my array:%@", array);
}

NSLog(@"items in my array: %lu", (unsigned long) [array count]);
```

Here are the views for the plist file im working with.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>New item</key>
<string>hello</string>
<key>New item - 2</key>
<string>world</string>
<key>New item - 3</key>
<string>again</string>
<key>New item - 4</key>
<string>and</string>
<key>New item - 5</key>
<string>again</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This code does not return null like when i tried using an NSArray over the NSDictionary, but when i run it console does not print out any data retrieved from the plist. It just prints out:

```
my array:{}
my array:{}
my array:{}
my array:{}
my array:{}
items in my array: 0
```

If i try to print out dict by changing the NSLog to NSLog(@"my array:%@", array); i get this.

```
my array:(NULL)
my array:(NULL)
my array:(NULL)
my array:(NULL)
my array:(NULL)
items in my array: 0
```

Comment: the description you've given of your plist file doesn't have a key called "root" and also contains no array.

Comment: Can you show the output from printing `dict`?

Comment: I added a NSLog that prints the list count to see how many values are in my array after adding the dictionary items into it and the out and the output for that was 0. So i believe my issue is that i dont have any objects in my array. My plist is a dictionary and there are actually 5 items in it, but for the question i just typed out one item. I will edit the new code in the original questiona s well as the new output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had to create a build phase and add the plist files to it. That way when i use the pathToResource ofFile it has a file to find when i use the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put all the values form the dict into the array ?
If so add:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dict allValues]];
```

//Check for file;

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
    NSLog(@"NO FILE AT PATH: %@", path);
```

Comment: I added this and also added an NSLog that prints out [dict count] to see how many of the plist objects were actually stored into my dictionary and it printed 0, then i did the count method for my array and it also has 0 objects in it. Any thoughts?

Comment: There's nothing in your dictionary so there won't be anything in your array.

Comment: Is there an issue with my code? I thought that my code would store the content my plist inside of my dictionary.

Comment: I found the issue, but i need to find the solutoin. My path is nil and cannot find the plist file. If i use pathforresource of type indirectory is there a way to get it to look at my supporting files?

Comment: Are you sure the plist is included in your build ? Also check case as it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you could print for such plist is
NSLog(dict[@"new item"]);

Also you probably should use

```
for(int num = 0; num < array.count; num++)
{
    NSLog(@"my array:%@", array[i]);
}
```

instead of

```
for(int num = 0; num < 5; num++)
{
    NSLog(@"my array:%@", array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what keys are in dictionary? No need to concern about keys in this case. Try this

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
if(dict.count != 0)
  {
    NSArray *array = [dict allKeys];
    for(int num = 0; num < array.count; num++)
      {
        NSLog(@"my array item:%@", [dict objectForKey:array[num]]);
      }
  }
else
  {
    NSLog(@"Your dictionary is empty.");
  }
```